# Unhandled exception (http error 500) when using Bottle with AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, bottle

This is the JS code, its just meant to send a request to the server then print the response. It sends it fine but I get a 500 error with the response

```
function UsernameCheck(){ 
var Username = document.getElementById('username').value;   
console.log('Test!');
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/CheckUsername',
        data:'username='+ Username,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    $('#UsernameCheck').html(response);
        }  
});
}
```

This is the python code for the request. The prints work fine and it queries the database correctly but the response doesn't work and I am unsure how to fix it

```
@route('/CheckUsername')
def CheckUsername():
    username = request.query.username
    print(username)
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=mysqlDom,
                   user=mysqlUser,
                   passwd=mysqlPass,
                   db=mysqlDB)
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute(SeeIfUserExsistsSQL, [username])
    count = cur.rowcount
    print(count)
    return count
```

If you need the whole Python code let me know but I believe that is all that is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast explicitly to a string when returning the count.
Bottle views need to return specific data types and int is not one of them.
See [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content).